# How to connect ESP32

Tags: esp32, arduino-uno, fatal-error, arduino-esp32

I am getting the following eroor while connecting ESP32

Arduino: 1.8.19 (Windows Store 1.8.57.0) (Windows 10), Board: "ESP32 Dev Module, Disabled, Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 921600, None"

Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"

In file included from C:\Users\Ayan Atal\Desktop\College\SEM 6\Minor\Ultrasonic\Ultrasonic.ino:3:0:

Used: C:\Users\Ayan Atal\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\WiFi

C:\Users\Ayan Atal\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer-master\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:33:22: fatal error: AsyncTCP.h: No such file or directory

Not used: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\WiFi

compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: install the AsyncTCP library

Answer (score 0):

There is library name conflicts. I usually solve this by first uninstalling Arduino IDE and then deleting arduino libraries, and then reinstalling everything from scratch. Sometimes using older versions of arduino IDE also had helped.
Thank You,
Have a Great Day,
Naveen.